# TinyMCE Custom Colors adds in grey when it's not in the list

Tags: tinymce, colormap, greybox

I've loaded a tinyMCE text editor from their CDN and set up a custom palette using the following code:

```
color_map: ['3b5665', 'color1', 'd8d6d2', 'color2', 'ffffff', 'color3', '000000', 'color4'];
```

The text editor appears fine but when clicking on the text color option it is showing a random grey box on the far right:

[image: Grey box on far right]

The box is selectable and has a hex code of #c3c3c4 but isn't in my color map. Does anyone have any idea where this grey box is coming from and how to get rid of it?